# How to suggest a Tag-edit without making any change in the main post?

Tags: support, retagging

Whenever I try to do any tag-edit  for the first-time-on-a-question, an error-message comes "your edit should contain change in at-least 6 characters".

When a little tag-edit-suggestion could make a great improvement to the question, where-as I have nothing to change on the main-question, what should I do?

(Also, I could alter a few words keeping the meaning of the question unaltered, but I feel this unfair since I had no intention to do that change in main question. Also, many other Stack sites doesn't require any edit on main post to do a tag edit. Could that be done for this community?)

Update:

- 1. Sometimes it takes the tag-edit easily (as said by user@AliceD). In some cases it show warning for few edit-save attempts but then saves the edits. And in some cases it really don't take the edit. I really don't understand the mechanism behind this. Maybe there is a reputation dependent privilege.
- 2. In a recent [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60765/is-there-a-reliable-estimate-of-the-number-of-cells-on-earth/60766#60766) I did a very minor edit (Pro`c`aryote -> pro`K`aryote) and it brought exactly same warning message; "Edits must be 6 characters at least, is there anything to improve?" near the edit description field.

[image: FIRST ATEMPT]

I really had not to do any more modifications so I added some more blank spaces. It just changed the position of the message, from edit-description field to edit field. Nothing else.

[image: Second attempt]

I searched at the [Help center](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) such as entered in the seach box as ["edit must be 6-charactere"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=Edit%20must%20be%206-character). But I found no article about this.

The second point is nothing about tag suggest; but the same message box is the cause.

..............................

## UPDATE:

Got a typical example. [image: Typical example].

Really mysterious... it happens only sometimes but not always.

Comment: I just happen to come across this post. I don't see any reason why you should not be able to change tags. It may have to be reviewed by others, depending on one's reputation.